# JavaCV FaceRecognizer predict not working

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, javacv, face-recognition

I'm using opencv 2.4.6 and javacv 0.6. I'm trying to make face recognizer.
This is my code:

```
    FaceRecognizer ef = createEigenFaceRecognizer(1, 0.00000001);
    int facewidth = 92, faceheight = 112;
    private boolean stopRec = false;
    List<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();

    public void recognize(IplImage face) {
        int predicted;
        int [] tabPredicted = new int[2];
        double[] predConfTab = new double[2];
        IplImage resizedFace = IplImage.create(new CvSize(facewidth,  faceheight), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);
        cvResize(face, resizedFace);
        if (names.size() != 0)
        {
           ef.predict(resizedFace, tabPredicted, predConfTab);
           predicted = tabPredicted[0];
        }
        else
        {
               predicted = -1;
        }

        if(predicted == -1 ) 
        {
           //adding user like: 
           int i = names.size();
           names.add(name);
           System.out.println("Identified new person: " + names.get(i));
           MatVector mv = new MatVector(1);
           mv.put(0, resizedFace);
           int[] u = new int[] {i};
           ef.train(mv, u);
        }
```

I tried lot of configurations. I'm sure that i have valid face image in grayscale. The problem is that after `ef.predict(resizedFace, tabPredicted, predConfTab);` 
`tabPredicted[0]` is always index of last added user and `predConfTab[0]` always equals 0, so it means that any faces exacly matches the last one added.